# Error creating a size for a vector of Structs C++

Tags: c++

This is for a project I am doing for my college class and I could not find an answer for this that worked for me anywhere.  Its very likely I did not understand the answers though.

I have a struct (menuItem), and that struct is put into a class (Menu).  I have successfully created an array of struct menuItem inside class Menu before, but when I try to create a vector of menuItem inside Menu I get this error when I try to initialize its size

> error C2059: syntax error : 'constant'

This is the offending code:

```
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

//previous array value
const int MAXCOUNT = 20;

struct menuItem
{
    void(*func)();
    char description[50];
};

class Menu
{
private:
    std::vector<menuItem> mi(20); // <<< "The error occurs when I set the vector to a size of 20"
    int count;
    void runSelection();
};
```

This error does not pup up when I initialize the vector as sizeless, but it pops up once again the second I use `mi.resize(20);` in the form of this contextual error: "Error, this deceleration has no storage class or type specifier", which makes no sense because I set the type of the vector `mi` as type `menuItem` per how I believe vectors are initialized.

I am assuming I am initializing the vector wrong somehow, or I am setting up the struct wrong.  I've found "answers" stating that structs are classes without a private section which I knew, and that you have to have a constructor to initialize a vector of structs, which I did not know.  Problem is, no constructor I've come up with has made the error go away.  I am completely lost and would appreciate some assistance.

Comment: making the code as `code sample` should be better to read.

Comment: Seems like you put `mi.resize(20);` outside of a function.

Comment: This is the code as I want it to be, without using a mi.resize(20).  I just wanted to state that doing mi.resize(20) did not seem to fix the issue either.

Thank you btw for the advice raison, First time posting here did not realize that existed.

Comment: _"I've found 'answers' stating that structs are classes without a private section which I knew"_ Nope, incorrect.

Comment: I see, I guess that was just another thing that I took incorrectly *sigh*

Comment: Ok so I understand my issue now, I was setting up the size inside the member area when I was supposted to setup the size in the classes constructor.  Thank you everyone for the help, its interesting how its so different for a vector compared to an array, but I kind of understand now why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in C++11 like so

```
class Menu
{
private:
    std::vector<menuItem> mi = std::vector<menuItem>(20);
};
```

or if you are stuck using C++03 you will need to initialize it in the constructors initializer list

```
class Menu
{
public:
    Menu() : mi(20) {}

private:
    std::vector<menuItem> mi;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

For class members, you do not initialise them where you declare them (as the list of members is just that: a list of types and names), but instead in the constructor's *member initialisation list*.

Like this:

```
class Menu
{
    std::vector<menuItem> mi;    // no initialiser here

    Menu() : mi(20) {};          // but in the ctor-initializer instead
};
```

Comment: Not as inline as you'd like. `{20}` will use the list constructor and `(20)` isn't allowed in an NSDMI.

Comment: @chris Yeah it becomes a pain. That's why I didn't want to go into it here. Though until your comment I forgot that it's _even harder_ than I remember! In fact, I shall just remove that addendum accordingly :)

Comment: Yeah, it's a shame that's really only that bad for types with list constructors. And then of course `auto mi = std::vector<menuItem>(20);` doesn't work because `auto` isn't allowed in NSDMIs either.

Comment: omg, do you mean my issue is im trying to setup how many vectors of my struct exist inside the initialization of the class in the .h, when I should be doing it in a constructor inside the .ccp.

I should have known that...

Comment: @Stephen: Your terminology is off, but... yeah, more or less.

Comment: Im still a bit new to C++ even though this is my level 2 class on it, so I except my terminology to be a bit off.  So just create it sizeless and initialize the size via resize inside the class constructor I assume.

Comment: @Stephen: You don't need to resize. Initialise it just as I show in my answer. This is a confusing aspect of C++ that is fixed to some extent in recent versions of the standard (though unfortunately not in a way that properly helps you here) — when you name the member `mi`, you're not "creating it sizeless": you're just saying that it exists. By initialising it in the constructor's member initialisation list, as I demonstrate in my answer, you're then finally saying "create it with size 20". Your C++ book should cover this, though it may be a few chapters in.

Comment: It's confusing because it's quite different from how you'd declare, define and initialise a local `std::vector<menuItem>` inside of, say, a function.

Comment: Ah, I think I understand now.  Its a bit confusing for me since when I used an array I was able to set how many spaces are in the array by simply saying the array had MAXCOUNT (or 20) slots during class creation, and now that im making a vector it wants me to set its size elsewhere.

Ya it is a bit confusing since everywhere I went it says "do it this way" but I never thought of "except do it THIS way if inside a class"

Comment: @Stephen: Yep. For your array, the type is `char[20]` — the dimension is part of the type. For initialising your vector the number 20 has nothing to do with the type but is instead a constructor argument. Two different beasts.

Comment: This is why more recent standards tried to address this and let you initialise the vector "inline", but it's still not quite right. The Captain's answer shows the only real way to do that with a vector, though I personally feel that this approach makes things even worse because it's code that would even look _weird_ in a local declaration and thus makes the confusion more potent. (Per my conversation with chris, above)

Comment: Ya after looking at all of the answers I chose captains as the easiest to understand.  Thank you for the information though lightness, it helped me to understand what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to pass parameters to a constructor of a non-static class member as part of the declaration, which is wrong.

Basically, you'll have to declare the data member in the declaration like this:

```
std::vector<menuitem> mi;
```

and as part of the constructor, call the appropriate resize, if that is even necessary.

Unless you know you need a minimum vector size of 20, I would forget about pre-sizing it and just let it grow as necessary.